# Is there a non-invasive way of preventing the computer from locking out after "x" seconds?

Tags: windows-8, group-policy

By non-invasive, I mean not having to install softwares/apps.

Due to a group policy, my work computer locks out after 60 seconds of inactivity. Though I understand why such a rule has been put into place, it sometimes turns out to be an inconvenience especially when I'm reading something online or turn around to talk/chat with a co-worker only to realize I have to type in my password again to get to the desktop.

Up until last week, we used to bypass the lock by keeping a program called as "*Join Me*" running in the background which prevented the system from idling. But today I found out that this hack no longer works for reasons unknown to me.

So I was wondering if there are any alternatives to keep this from happening.

PS: Since this is a work computer, I can't install any software without the help of the System Admin. So a non-install approach is preferable. I do, however, have access to **elevated command prompt** if that helps.

### Some Metadata

**OS: Windows 8.1**

Comment: If you are savvy enough, you could use something like an Arduino; some of the recent models can enumerate as hardware devices. You could therefore plug one of these devices into your computer, it would be seen as a mouse, and write a simple sketch to move the cursor a few pixels ever 20 minutes or so. The documentation is pretty good, and the support from the Arduino community is excellent. It wouldn't be a difficult project for a newcomer.

Comment: Good way to get fired.

Comment: @Moab Their loss I'd say if that happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Is there a non-invasive way of preventing the computer from locking out after “x” seconds?**
>
> Since this is a work computer, I can't install any software without
>   the help of the System Admin. So a non-install approach is preferable.
>   I do, however, have access to elevated command prompt if that helps.

Below is a batch script that will use [**SendKeys**](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) and [**WScript.Sleep**](http://ss64.com/vb/sleep.html) functions to run a loop every 30 seconds to emulate pressing the **Scroll Lock** button on your keyboard which is keyboard activity.

Save the below logic to a text file on the desktop, etc. and name it to `<something>.cmd`, and then simple double-click it for it to run. Watch the scroll lock light on your keyboard toggle off and on every 30 seconds.

Simply minimize the command prompt window when it's running, and simply close that command prompt window with the "X" when you're ready to stop if from running for your PC to actually lock after 1 minute of inactivity.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET TempVBSFile=%tmp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs

:VBSDynamicBuildLoop
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 30000                                  >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{SCROLLLOCK}"                     >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"

CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"
GOTO VBSDynamicBuildLoop
```

Comment: Seems to be working. +1 and accepted